# Add some parameters to FilterSet (django-filter) + some parameters

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter, django-filters

i have 3 models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, )

class Products(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

and i have a view which receive `request` and `category.slug`

```
def category_list(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    products = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Products.objects.filter(category=category)

    return render(request, 'products/category_list.html', {"products":products, 'category': category})
```

when rendering i receive a `QuerySet` filtered to `Category`

I want to send `category.id` to `ProductsFilter` and recive a dynamic Choices from database

```
class ProductsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    subcategory= django_filters.ChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='iexact', choices=TEST, required=False)       

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = {
            "subcategory",
        }
```

Want to change `choices=TEST` to `choices=list(SubCategory.objects.filter(category_id=category.id)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in the `FilterSet.__init__` method. Something like the below (Note that I haven't tested it, may require some fiddling):

```py
class ProductsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    subcategory= django_filters.ChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='iexact', choices=[], required=False)

    def __init__(self, category, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductsFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        choices = self.fields['subcategory'].extra['choices']
        choices += [
            (subcat.name, subcat.name) for subcat 
            in SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
        ]

    class Meta:
        model = Products
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Sherpa has just two slight problems. First, you should replace `fields` with `filters`. Second, you can't use `+=` operator, you have to directly assign to the filter's `extra`.
Here's my working code in two different ways

```
class LayoutFilterView(filters.FilterSet):
    supplier = filters.ChoiceFilter(
        label=_('Supplier'), empty_label=_("All Suppliers"),)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutFilterView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # First Method
        self.filters['supplier'].extra['choices'] = [
            (supplier.id, supplier.name) for supplier in ourSuppliers(request=self.request)
        ]

        # Second Method
        self.filters['supplier'].extra.update({
            'choices': [(supplier.id, supplier.name) for supplier in ourSuppliers(request=self.request)]
        })
```

Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585218/4157431)