# django-filter: Using ChoiceFilter with choices dependent on request

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter, choicefield

I am using django-filter and need to add a `ChoiceFilter` with choices dependent on the request that I receive. I am reading the docs for ChoiceFilter but it says: `This filter matches values in its choices argument. The choices must be explicitly passed when the filter is declared on the FilterSet`.

So is there any way to get request-dependent choices in the `ChoiceFilter`?

I haven't actually written the code but the following is what I want -

```
class F(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(choices=?) #choices depend on request
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['status']
```

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#request-based-filtering)? Your FilterSet is initialised with the `request` (which may be `None` so you should check), so you can use `request` object in the filter's `__init__()` method and declare the `status` field there.

Comment: You can also use a [custom method](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) which has access to the filterset's `request` property.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried doing `self.fields['status'] = ChoiceFilter(choices=...)` in `__init__` but was getting some error. I'm currently out so cannot check but iirc the problem was with `self.fields['status']` being set like this.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry I just came back and checked. I get the following error: 
`'F' object has no attribute 'fields'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking too hard that I found two different ways of doing it! (both by overriding the `__init__` method). Code inspired from [this](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/749) question.

```
class LayoutFilterView(filters.FilterSet):
    supplier = filters.ChoiceFilter(
        label=_('Supplier'), empty_label=_("All Suppliers"),)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutFilterView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # First Method
        self.filters['supplier'].extra['choices'] = [
            (supplier.id, supplier.id) for supplier in ourSuppliers(request=self.request)
        ]

        # Second Method
        self.filters['supplier'].extra.update({
            'choices': [(supplier.id, supplier.name) for supplier in ourSuppliers(request=self.request)]
        })
```

The function `ourSuppliers` is just to return a QuerySet to be used as choices

```
def ourSuppliers(request=None):
    if request is None:
        return Supplier.objects.none()

    company = request.user.profile.company
    return Supplier.objects.filter(company=company)
```

Comment: Where is 'ourSuppliers' being defined here?

Comment: I added the definition of `ourSuppliers` .. it's just a function to return the desired QuerySet to be used as your choices